# RecordNotUnique Error showing up in the logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise

I have a pretty standard devise setup with a User model. There is a unique index on email for that table in the schema.

When a user tries to signup a nice error message is given - email already taken.

Occasionally, in the logs an error shows up:

```
/app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb", line 5 in create:    
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
```

It isn't a race-condition because the error has been reported days after the user first signed up.

I can't recreated the issue by signing up on the site with the existing email.

What might be happening here? I'm not sure what steps to take to investigate it.

UPDATE: Registrations code:

```
  def create
    super  #ln 5
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      flash[:tracking_partial] = "registration_complete"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the registrations controller?  Also, for your migration, which fields have unique indexes?

Comment: updated to show the error is on email index.  users have unique index on email, invitation_token, reset_password_token @MichaelGaskill

Comment: Wow, that's crazy that you can't reproduce the error.  Have you checked what action caused this in the Rails log?  And have you cross-checked the web server access log against this to see who (which IP) has caused this?  One of my sites got hit with some wannabe hacker that had correctly guessed some (publicly available) email addresses used on the site and tried to brute force in.  He left tracks all over the Rails log and access logs.

Comment: i checked the IP addresses.  they are coming from Australia, the sites target market.  It doesn't seem to be hacking.